# Opposite of find(isnan)

Tags: matlab, if-statement, nan

I am testing a vector to see whether it contains any NaNs. If it does, then I don't want my action to be performed. If it contains no NaNs, the action should be performed. At present, my code looks like this (and it works):

```
if find(isnan(myVector))
else
    action;
end
```

Since there is nothing in the `if` section, having my action under the `else` clause seems sloppy. How do I go about rephrasing the block so that I don't need to use the `else`?

I have already tried the following:

```
if ~find(isnan(myVector))
if find(~isnan(myVector))
if find(isfinite(myVector))
```

To clarify, my input vector could contain any number of NaNs, but I *only* want 'action;' to execute if there are none at all.

Comment: Please clean up your question; currently it is contradictory: you wrote: "If it contains even a single NaN, the action should be performed." as well as "To clarify, my input vector could contain any number of NaNs, but I only want 'action;' to execute if there are none at all."

Comment: Intead of `find(isnan(myVector))`, you should use `any(isnan(myVector))`. It's faster and cleaner, since `any` produces boolean output rather than a vector.

Comment: SO should allow answers to be selected immediately! The ten minute wait meant I chose the wrong one by accident >.<

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if all(~isnan(myVector))
    action;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if isempty(find(isnan(myVector)))
    action;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1713724/1324631).  You could try to find all the NaN elements and then count them, if your data set is sufficently small.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is find is returning a vector instead of a boolean. What you want is something like:

```
length(find(isnan(myVector))) == 0
```

Though I admit I don't recall how matlab compares vectors.